# accessing VMware through java code

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Is there a way that a virtual machine (.vmx) file be opened in VMware workstation through a java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit the .vmx file, then the answer is no. There is currently no API available for VMware Workstation to let you programmatically change values in vmx file.

**EDIT:**

If VMPlayer can be invoked command line and an agrument vmx file can be passwd to it, then yes. Run the command via java using Process object.

Comment: no .. what i want to do is that i want to start VMware workstation using a java program and then run a guest operating system ( or load a vmx file) on the VMware workstation( that was started programatically) using a java program again.